# .company Top Level Domain

Tags: top-level-domains

I want to know about the disadvantages of starting a website with a .company TLD instead of .com, .net and the like. I've read some opinions suggesting not to use it because of SEO but there were no further explanation, can anyone explain the disadvantages ?

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/top-level-domains

Comment: Sorry but the question appears to be opinionated and duplicate. To avoid further disappointment please visit our help centre.

Comment: You can also review the differences between TLD and CCTLD here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/33955/advantages-of-country-tld-vs-com bottom line is, a domain is a domain... there's no real advantages using any TLD type other than the fact .com is the easiest to remember since its the most commonly used for big websites that are among the top most visited in the world.